# MS Access 2016 move record to different table

Tags: ms-access

I have a simple database that is used to store reports generated by officers within my department. I need to find a way to "lock" reports once they're completed and submitted by an officer. Once a report is locked, it can be opened but not modified.

I've tried to use the "Allow Edits" property but that won't work because if an officer is working on a report and closes the window, they can no longer modify it, even if they haven't completed and submitted it.

I thought of a few ways to do this, but I'm not sure exactly how to do any of them.

1. Have a "Submit Report" button on the form that once clicked, copies the record from the "Reports" table to the "Completed Reports" table. The information in the "Completed Reports" table is read only.

I don't really have a preference on how it works, I just need to have it so once a report is submitted, it cannot be modified

any thoughts on how I could go about doing this?

Comment: Are you familiar with VBA? you could have a check box then add VBA procedure to the `afterupdate()` event. This would disable and lock specific fields (or all). you could also put code in the `beforeupdate()` event to prevent the check box from been unchecked.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Access or VBA, but I can work my way around things. I do have a box named "Locked" with "YES" and "NO" as the options. How would I go about doing this and would it just lock that specific record, or would it be locking those fields on the form so they can't be filled out even when creating a new record?

Comment: Make the "Submit Report" button set a "Locked" flag in the table. Then save the record. Check the Locked flag in the Current event and set the "Allow Edits" property accordingly.